# Ember tooltip pass variable

Tags: ember.js

I am building an Ember tooltip module to create dynamic content on hover.

```
<div class="custom-tool-wrapper">
  {{#custom-tool-tipster
     side="right"
     content=(or getContent question.id)
     contentAsHTML=true
     class="tool-tipster-field"}}
        Preview
  {{/custom-tool-tipster}}
</div>
```

in the ember controller - the function doesn't return the variable "question.id" --- it comes back as 0 always - when it should be a string "q-1"

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

  getContent(tips){
    console.log("tips1")
    console.log("question", tips);
  },

});
```

Comment: what are you expecting `(or getContent question.id)` to do? It's also very unclear from your question what it is your asking.

Comment: to pass question.id into getContent

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're actually trying to achieve is best done via [computed property](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/object-model/computed-properties/) on the `question` model object (your question is still really vague).

```
content: computed('id', function(){
   //this.tips is a part of the model object
   //compute and return whatever the content is
   return "content";
}
```

and then just say:

```
{{#custom-tool-tipster
     side="right"
     content=model.content
     contentAsHTML=true
     class="tool-tipster-field"}}
        Preview
{{/custom-tool-tipster}}
```

If you needed to actually invoke a function (which it's rare to think of an instance where the computed property isn't a better solution whenever state is involved), you would use a custom [handlebars helper](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/hbs-helper/).

`(or a b)` is `(a || b)` and isn't function invocation like you're attempting if you're using the `ember truth helpers` lib for the `or` helper. It looks like you're trying to accomplish what [ember-invoke](https://github.com/thoov/ember-invoke) allows

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { helper } from '@ember/component/helper';

export function invokeFunction([context, method, ...rest]) {
  if (typeof context[method] !== 'function') {
    throw new Error(`Method '${method}' is not defined or cannot be invoked.`);
  }

  return Ember.get(context,method).apply(context, rest);
}

export default helper(invokeFunction);
```

which can be used like `content=(invoke this "getContent" question.id)` to invoke and return the value of a function on the passed in context object (the controller if `this` in the case of a route's template). Let me be clear, I think this `invoke` approach is a terrible idea and really gets rid of your separation of concerns and I'm not advocating that you do it. Templates shouldn't contain your logic and definitely shouldn't be calling arbitrary functions on the controller when you have such a nice facility like computed properties.